# Autofac equivalent of StructureMap's WhatDoIHave()

Tags: c#, autofac

Does Autofac have an analog to [StructureMap's `WhatDoIHave()`](http://structuremap.github.io/diagnostics/whatdoihave/) method? I'd like to be able to see a visual representation of what services are currently registered in my container. I've looked at Autofac's documentation and can't find anything similar.

If such a method does not exist, is there a technical issue with Autofac that makes it difficult to implement or has there just not been any interest in providing something like it?

Comment: No technical issue.  Glimpse has an Autofac module that lists registrations in a similar format to the `WhatDoIHave()` results.  I'm unaware of any built-in visualization aids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RegistrationFor` method of an `IComponentRegistry` to get all registered service. You can access the component registry with the `ComponentRegistry` method of a `IComponentContext` (ie : a `ILifetimeScope` a `IContainer`)

```
IContainer container = builder.Build(); 

container.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationFor(new TypedService(typeof(IXService));
```